# EditText addTextChangedListener getting message source not found

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-edittext, android-widget

here, i want whenever user will change the value of edittext then value of textview also change with the use of multiplication by quantity edittext, but whenever i want to change edittext value before that an error message comes, source not found - VeiwRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRoot$QueueInputEvent) line: 3125

i am also placing some code:-

```
edit_qty_regular_code.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            text_price_regular_code.setText (Integer.toString(qty));
        }

        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
          int count, int after) {
            x=Integer.parseInt(text_price_regular_code.getText().toString());
        }

        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, 
          int before, int count) 
        {
                qty=Integer.parseInt (edit_qty_regular_code.getText().toString());
                qty=(int) ((int)qty*(int)x);

        }
       });
```

Logcat Report

```
10-13 14:06:26.359: I/System.out(664): waiting for debugger to settle...
10-13 14:06:26.559: I/System.out(664): debugger has settled (1478)
10-13 14:06:28.019: 
D/dalvikvm(664): GC_CONCURRENT freed 82K, 
3% free 8328K/8519K, paused 34ms+20ms, total 125ms
10-13 14:06:28.880: I/Choreographer(664): Skipped 61 frames!  
The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-13 14:06:29.199: D/gralloc_goldfish(664): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-13 14:06:32.689: I/Choreographer(664): Skipped 227 frames!  
The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

but if i will place these four line of codes in checkbox tick event then i am not getting problem...please tell me where i am doing mistake

Comment: try the same thing in afterTextChangedListener and let me know what you are getting??

Comment: ok nick i will try buddy

Comment: nick, i have tried by put these four lines of code under afterTextChanged, but still getting same problem and error message

Comment: plese post your logcat and edit with some more code to get it judge properly

Comment: nick, buddy please see the changes i have made in my program and also uploaded LOGCAT